# Flutter dynamic height of ListView

Tags: flutter

I am developing a **Flutter** application and I want to dynamically adjust the height of the ListView.

I want the list to have a maximum height of `200`. If the height is more than that, user will have to scroll to reach the bottom. If height is below `200`, it will take only as much space as needed.

Preview of application: [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q0bgD.png). As you can see `Restaurants nearby` is pushed to the very bottom of the page. I want the ListView to only take height of `200` or less so that the content below isn't pushed to the bottom.

Here is my current code:

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Container(
    padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
    child: Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: <Widget>[
        Text(
          'Restaurants nearby',
          style: TextStyle(
            fontSize: 20.0,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
          ),
        ),
        Divider(),
        Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            RaisedButton(
              child: Text('Enter restaurant manually'),
              onPressed: () {
                print('Button pressed');
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
        Flexible(
          child: ListView.builder(
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
              return ListTile(
                leading: CircleAvatar(
                  backgroundColor: Colors.cyan,
                ),
                title: Text('Test restaurant'),
                subtitle: Text('80m'),
              );
            },
            itemCount: 15,
          ),
        ),
        Text(
          'Restaurants nearby',
          style: TextStyle(
            fontSize: 20.0,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  );
}
```

Comment: Hi @Bill, Did you resolve this issue?

Answer (score 40):

You are using `Flexible` widget, that's why your `ListView` expands. You have to change `Flexible` to `ConstrainedBox` and add `shrinkWrap: true` to your `ListView`.

```
ConstrainedBox(
  constraints: BoxConstraints(maxHeight: 200, minHeight: 56.0),
  child: ListView.builder(
    shrinkWrap: true,
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
        return ListTile(
          leading: CircleAvatar(
            backgroundColor: Colors.cyan,
          ),
          title: Text('Test restaurant'),
          subtitle: Text('80m'),
        );
      },
    itemCount: 15,
  ),
),
```

More info here: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ConstrainedBox-class.html

Comment: The height is not dynamic in this case. If `ListView` has height less than `200`, then `SizedBox` will still take height of `200`. I don't want that. I want to have height automatically adjusted based on the height of the list, but not more than `200`. If it is more than `200`, then user has to scroll to reach the bottom of `ListView`.

Comment: ConstrainedBox doesn't answer the question, LimitedBox does

Answer (score 22):

You can use [LimitedBox](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/LimitedBox-class.html)

```
Column(
  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
  children: <Widget>[
    Text(...),
    Divider(),
    Row(...),
    LimitedBox(
      maxHeight: 200.0,
      child: ListView.builder(...),
    ),
    Text(...),
  ],
),
```

Recommended solution in case when the incoming constraints are unbounded

Answer (score 8):

Consider wrapping the `ListView` into this

```dart
LimitedBox(
  maxHeight: 200,
  child: Column(
    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
    children: [
      Flexible(
        child: ListView.builder(
          shrinkWrap: true,
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
            return ListTile(
              leading: CircleAvatar(
                backgroundColor: Colors.cyan,
              ),
              title: Text('Test restaurant'),
              subtitle: Text('80m'),
            );
          },
          itemCount: _itemsCount,
        ),
      ),
    ]
  )
),
```

Note that:

- `shrinkWrap` of `ListView` is set to `true`
- `mainAxisSize` of `Column` is set to `MainAxisSize.min`
- `maxHeight` of `LimitedBox` is set to `200`

A complete snippet:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class DebugWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _DebugWidgetState createState() => _DebugWidgetState();
}
class _DebugWidgetState extends State<DebugWidget> {
  int _itemsCount = 1;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Widget child = Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: <Widget>[
          Text(
            'Restaurants nearby',
            style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 20.0,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
            ),
          ),
          Divider(),
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              RaisedButton(
                child: Text('Enter restaurant manually'),
                onPressed: () {
                  print('Button pressed');
                },
              ),
              RaisedButton(
                child: Text('+1'),
                onPressed: () {
                  setState(() {
                    _itemsCount += 1;
                  });
                },
              ),
              RaisedButton(
                child: Text('-1'),
                onPressed: () {
                  setState(() {
                    _itemsCount -= 1;
                  });
                },
              ),
            ],
          ),
          LimitedBox(
            maxHeight: 200,
            child: Column(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              children: [
                Flexible(
                  child: ListView.builder(
                    shrinkWrap: true,
                    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                      return ListTile(
                        leading: CircleAvatar(
                          backgroundColor: Colors.cyan,
                        ),
                        title: Text('Test restaurant'),
                        subtitle: Text('80m'),
                      );
                    },
                    itemCount: _itemsCount,
                  ),
                ),
              ]
            )
          ),
          Text(
            'Restaurants nearby',
            style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 20.0,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );

    return Scaffold(
      body: child,
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

I found a solution to this problem. you should wrap your ListView with LimittedBox or ConstraintBox and give them maxHeight and set shrinkWrap property of ListView to true. the solution would be something like this.

```
LimitedBox(
          maxHeight: 200,
          child: ListView.builder(
            shrinkWrap: true,
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
              return ListTile(
                leading: CircleAvatar(
                  backgroundColor: Colors.cyan,
                ),
                title: Text('Test restaurant'),
                subtitle: Text('80m'),
              );
            },
            itemCount: 15,
          ),
        ),
```

Answer (score 3):

I see that this question has never been answered only with giving a fixed height, so here is what works for me.

For some reason if you set the shrinkwrap to true it doesn't look like it is working but it does, the problem is in the padding settings of the ListView, set the padding to edgeinstets.zero. That fixes it for me.

- Wrap inside a Flexible
- ShrinkWrap true
- Padding, zero
- and if needed the column to MainAxisSize.min.

Hope it helps some people.

Example of my code:

```
Flexible(
                  child: Container(
                    decoration: BStyles.cardDecoration1,
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                      child: Column(
                        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          const Text(
                            'PRODUCTION TASKS',
                          ),
                          const SizedBox(
                            height: textVerticalSpacing,
                          ),
                          Flexible(
                            child: ListView.builder(
                              itemCount: recentTasks.length,
                              padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                              physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                              shrinkWrap: true,
                              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                                return TaskCard(
                                  task: recentTasks[index],
                                  widthInfo: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.6,
                                );
                              },
                            ),
                          ),
                          const SizedBox(
                            height: itemSpacing,
                          ),
                          Align(
                            alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                            child: InkWell(
                              onTap: () { },
                              child: const Text(
                                'View more',
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                          const SizedBox(
                            height: textVerticalSpacing,
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
```

Answer (score 1):

```
ConstrainedBox(
  constraints: BoxConstraints(maxHeight: 200.0),
  child: [your child here],
)
```

This make your child's height not bigger than 200.0

Comment: If we define `minHeight` then, how it restricts the `maxHeight` ?

Answer (score 0):

What was preventing mine from sizing dynamically was having it inside a `Scaffold`. Once I removed the `Scaffold` it worked. I didn't have a maximum height requirement for mine so to make it size dynamically all I had to do was set `shrinkWrap` to `true` and put it inside a `Flexible` widget. eg.

```
Column(
  children: [
    Flexible(
      ListView.separated(shrinkWrap: true, ...)
    )
  ]
)
```

Answer (score -1):

You can always size the ListView container as % of the viewport (assuming of course that the other widgets also are sized in the same manner):

```
return Container(
      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.75,
      child: ListView.builder(
        itemBuilder: (ctx, index) {
          return Card(...
```